# Read a local text file constantly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little lost on how I can read a local text file constantly. Nothing is going to a webserver, everything is done locally and its just something basic.

Essentially I have a text file that is getting updated constantly (A different program is writing to the text file), and I want to be able to read that text file. I just want to do something basic where a div gets auto updated with text file content without refreshing the page.

Comment: @ggorlen they do actually.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) for canonical FS access from browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the [File System Access](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/) API we can now keep live links to resources on the disk and request their content when we wish. (Previously, Files only kept a [snapshot](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#snapshot-state) of a file on disk).

So in modern Chrome we can now request access to a file on disk using the [`window.showOpenFilePicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker) method.
This will return a list of handles, from which we will be able to call the [`getFile()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/getFile) method to get an up-to-date snapshot of the file on disk.

```
// must come from an user gesture
onclick = async () => {
  
  if( !("showOpenFilePicker" in self) ) {
    throw new Error( "unsupported browser" );
  }

  const handles = await showOpenFilePicker();
  
  setInterval( async () => {
    const file = await handles[0].getFile();
    document.getElementById( "log" ).textContent = await file.text();
  }, 1000 );
  
};
```

Since this API is over-protected, it can't run in cross-domain iframes, so here is an outsourced [glitch demo](https://graceful-canary-shear.glitch.me/), which currently works only in Chrome.

Comment: Interesting approach. Would there also be a possibility to directly access a local file without having to go through the file picker?

Comment: @cars10m That would be a massive security breach.
What will then be stopping a malicious website from deleting your files without your intervention

Comment: Certainly true :D - I was just wondering ... ;-)